# ASP.NET Core 5 MVC: version number in footer

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, .net-5, asp.net-core-5.0

I'm migrating an old ASP.NET MVC project to ASP.NET Core 5. In the old project my pages had a base object inherited from `WebViewPage` that does not exist anymore in .NET 5.

With this class I added e.g. the version number to the footer in `_Layout.cshtml`.

How do I do that in ASP.NET Core 5 MVC? What is the best approach to get the version number in the footer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want the *best* or the *simplest*?

The *best* would probably be to fetch the version number of your app once, at startup, and store it somewhere for later - e.g. in cache (if you're already using cache), or some other place.

The *simplest* would probably be to just simply change the existing `_layout.cshtml` and amend the `<footer>` element like this:

```
<footer class="border-top footer text-muted">
    <div class="container">
        &copy; 2021 - YourAppName - version @Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()?.GetName()?.Version?.ToString(3) - <a asp-area="" asp-page="/Privacy">Privacy</a>
    </div>
</footer>
```

Just add the part `version @Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()?.GetName()?.Version?.ToString(3)` to your footer HTML element - that's it